# Strange behavior in singularsys Jep

Tags: java

Recently, I did some test on singularsys Jep, I have below snippet,

```
    Jep jep = new Jep();
    jep.parse("x*2");

    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        if (i <= 2) {
            jep.addVariable("x", i);
        }
        try {
            System.out.println(jep.evaluate());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("N/A");
        }
    }
```

What I expect is,

```
2.0  4.0  N/A  N/A  N/A
```

While the real result is,

```
2.0  4.0  4.0  4.0  4.0
```

Then I realize jep keeps the variable value used last time, so I update my code to call jep.getVariableTable().clearValues(),

```
    Jep jep = new Jep();
    jep.parse("x*2");

    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        jep.getVariableTable().clearValues();
        if (i <= 2) {
            jep.addVariable("x", i);
        }
        try {
            System.out.println(jep.evaluate());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("N/A");
        }
    }
```

I can see that the variable value in variableTable is null when i>2, but the output is still,

```
2.0  4.0  4.0  4.0  4.0
```

I may have a big misunderstanding in Jep or variableTable, could anyone please help to give some explanations? Thanks.

Comment: Change `crearValues()` to `clear()`.

Comment: @saka1029  doesn't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this looks like a bug in the Jep system. The clearValues() methods sets a validValue flag in the Variable. Really the evaluator should test this flag before returning the value. (See [Variable API](http://www.singularsys.com/jep/doc/javadoc/com/singularsys/jep/Variable.html#setValidValue(boolean)))

A workaround is to use

```
for(Variable var:jep.getVariableTable().getVariables()) {
    var.setValue(null);
}
```

A better solution is to override the FastEvaluator

```
static class MyEvaluator extends FastEvaluator {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public Object visit(ASTVarNode node, Object data) throws EvaluationException {
        Variable var = node.getVar();
        if(!var.hasValidValue())
            throw new EvaluationException("Value not set");
        return super.visit(node, data);
    }
}
```

Which could then be used in the Jep constructor

```
Jep jep = new Jep(new MyEvaluator());
```

I'll fix the evaluator in the next release.